# Is it possible to access disks in an LVM after a reinstallation of the OS on a separate drive?

Tags: 14.04, lvm

I have a 120GB SSD hosting my Ubuntu installation.
I have four 3TB Western Digital Disks which I would like to configure into an LVM.

If I reinstall Ubuntu at any point in the future onto the SSD or indeed change the SSD for another, is it possible for me to access the LVM partitions etc. afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, as you can verify by building a small test diskset (for example by combining a handfull of files) and accessing it lateron from another installation or even a live CD / USB stick / whatever.
Don't forget to install the lvm2 package to the installation you want to use, if it isn't already present.

as root (or with sudo)

- `apt-get install lvm2`
- `pvscan` will show if the physical volume is detected
- `vgscan` searches for the volume group
- `modprobe dm-mod` to load the module
- `vgchange -ay`to activate the volumes
- `lvscan` should now show the logical volumes as active and mountable

see also: [how to move volume group to another system](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html)

I'd also recommend to use `vgfcbackup` to backup the configuration info of your volume group.

Comment: Just tried this by booting with a USB key.  I was able to access a temporary test Logical Volume.  Thank you.  Saved the information into a Springpad notebook.  Going to keep this safe :-)

Comment: Additional note - upon booting a second time with the USB key, I noticed the drive was automatically recognised and available anyway.  I had to drop to root because of permissions but was able to add additional items to the volume which were available to me after starting the computer normally.